# Working with jcrop: png - black image

Tags: jquery, jcrop

Im trying to use this jquery in my website: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

basically its a tool that allow to "cut" images.
It work fine since i work with a png (either with transparent background or not); if i try to cut a png, the new image the script save is totally black.

I found some links with people having my same issue and they have been suggested to put this parameter:     bgColor: 'transparent', instead of black and others solutions but nothing seems to work with me.

Does anybody used this plugin and encountered the same problem? anybody have a workaround?

thanks!

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I'm with the same problem and I partially solved the problem making an if like: $img_r = $type=='png'? imagecreatefrompng($src): imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
But when I have transparency, it appears totally black too.

Comment: No, i didnt solve that issue... i just found a workaround.
When someone try to crop a png image, i automatically turn it into jpg... it loose transparency but the user will be able to crop

Comment: Please link your php script and we will be able to help you out, as transparency should be handled via php not via Jcrop